# How to get Product name,price in Wordpress Woocommerce Products page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I just developed a wordpress woocommerce website and have many products with 5 categories.
I display the products category with following short code.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[product_categories number="20"]'); ?>
```

when clicking on one category its goes to products page and display products finely. but i want to view product in my own div, fonts,etc.
Currently i am working ( displaying ) on archive-product.php file.

my code is below.

```
 <div class="ProductCategoryWraper">

  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>


        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>


            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="CategoryBox"> <a href="product-details.html"> <img src="images/panda-product1.jpg">
    <p>Chicken Masala</p>
    <i class="fa fa-inr"></i> <span>42</span> </a> </div>
</div>
```

how can i filter the price & product name only from this. please help me. Thanks

Comment: I didn't get you. What do you exactly want to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Your content-single-product.php and add your own div css class.

Go here

**\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\content-single-product.php**

The For price 
 go here and add your own css div class.

**\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\price.php**

Comment: Its not recommended to change plugin's core file directly.

Comment: you can override it by making this file in your theme folder as your choice. if you know about woocommerece template structure.

Comment: You need to mention it in your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

To get product name and price on product pages override **content-single-product.php** and  **price.php**

Instead of editing these files directly within the plugin (which is a very bad idea because once update the plugin and all of your changes will be lost!), you can copy them into your theme:

- In your theme directory, make a new folder called “WooCommerce.”
- Navigate to the WooCommerce plugin directory and open the "templates" folder. The templates folder has a lot of subfolders with all of the different templates that WooCommerce uses. Fortunately, the template file structure and naming in WooCommerce is easy to follow.
- In your newly created "WooCommerce" folder, copy the template file that you want to edit.

> Remember to keep the directory structure the same here. If the
>   template you want to edit is within a subfolder then remember to
>   create that subfolder within your theme's directory.